# How to get cell value in automated mail via Google Sheets (& Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For some time I'm using a document in Google Sheets to fetch price data from a website. When a change is been made within our fetching sheet we receive an email notification (via Google Scripts). This works, but since there are a lot of changes per day I would like to get the cell location that has been changed within the email (so we know where to look directly). Does anyone know how I can change my script to also receive some data from the sheet itself (like the cell location that has been changed, the old cell data and the new cell data)? Thank you!

**Script**:

```
 function sendEmailAlert() {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
    var sheetname = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var Toemail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'New Entry in ' + data + '.' + ss.getName();
    var body = 'Your file has a new entry in - ' + sheetname + ' Updated by - ' + user + data
    ' check file- ' + ss.getUrl();
    
    if(data.indexOf('K2:K29')!=-1.23456789) {
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body);
     }
    
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementation depend on your workflow.

If you can get and store somewhere the old table and then get the new table you can compare them and get all the changes this way:

```js
// old table
const old_table = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
    ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4'],
];

// new table
const new_table = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', '', 'c2'],
    ['', 'b3', ''],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4'],
];

const abc = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ';

// get indexes of changed rows
const changed_rows = old_table.map( (row, i) =>
    (row.toString() != new_table[i].toString()) ? i : '' ).filter(String);

// get changes for every changed row
const changes = changed_rows.map( r =>
    old_table[r].map( (col, i) =>
        (col != new_table[r][i] ) ? {
            'cell': abc[i] + (r+1), 
            'old_value': col, 
            'new_value': new_table[r][i]
        } : '' ) .filter(String) ).filter(String).flat();

console.log(changes);
console.table(changes);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "cell": "B2",
    "old_value": "b2",
    "new_value": ""
  },
  {
    "cell": "A3",
    "old_value": "a3",
    "new_value": ""
  },
  {
    "cell": "C3",
    "old_value": "c3",
    "new_value": ""
  }
]

┌─────────┬──────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ (index) │ cell │ old_value │ new_value │
├─────────┼──────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│    0    │ 'B2' │   'b2'    │   ''    │
│    1    │ 'A3' │   'a3'    │   ''    │
│    2    │ 'C3' │   'c3'    │   ''    │
└─────────┴──────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

---

### Update

Here is another algorithm with the same output:

```js
// old table
const OLD_TABLE = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
    ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4'],
];

// new table
const NEW_TABLE = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', '', 'c2'],
    ['', 'b3', ''],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4'],
];

function get_obj(row, col) {
    var old_value = OLD_TABLE[row][col];
    var new_value = NEW_TABLE[row][col];

    if (old_value == new_value) return '';

    return {
        'cell': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ'[col] + (row+1),
        'old value': old_value,
        'new value': new_value
    }
}

const changes = OLD_TABLE.map( (row, r) =>
        row.map((_, c) => get_obj(r, c)) ).flat().filter(String);

console.log(changes);
console.table(changes);
```

### Finally

Sorry, I can't help... :) One-liner is here:

```
const changes = (tab1, tab2) => tab1.map((row, r) => row.map((_, c) =>
    tab1[r][c] == tab2[r][c] ? '' : ({ 
    'cell'      : 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ'[c] + (r + 1),
    'old_value' : tab1[r][c],
    'new_value' : tab2[r][c] }))).flat(2).filter(String);

console.log(changes(OLD_TABLE, NEW_TABLE));
```

The same output.

Comment: Hey Yuri, thank you for your comments and help. I'm not sure if I 100% get it already but I'm diving into the code. There are however some differences that I already noticed (and that I didn't mention earlier).

I collect the realtime values in column 'K'. The last known value (gets updated every day in between 10-11 oclock). At this moment I already receive an email when the sheet gets updated. When I do it myself I get an email that f.e. K10 is changed). When it is changed by the fetching formula it says A1 is changed... When fetch change it I want to know what cell (K) change + old (J).

Comment: I have an example sheet, may be it helps: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10kG9pFMwshaLeLDu7_uQrAb9O3cR2sOmFfH3jZRQbV4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, Sami. I'm sorry, I failed to understand your workflow this time. Probably my English isn't well enough. As far as I can see your comment contains the details that significantly shift your initial question (for me, at least). I think you can ask a new question (don't forget to add the link to your sheet) and, I believe, you will get the answer in no time from the cool local guys.

Comment: Thank you for your help Yuri, I will ask a new question!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just add whatever you like to the var body you have going. Here is some sample script for retrieving values from a sheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var activeCell = sheet.getRange("AE13")
var currentCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
```

You would use the OnChange method

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder

Creating the trigger:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onChange()
  .create();
```